# read multiple text files into r for text mining purposes

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a batch of text files that I need to read into r to do text mining.

So far, I have tried to use read.table, read.line, lapply, mcsv_r from qdap package to no avail. I have tried to write a loop to read the files, but I have to specify the name of the file, which changes in every iteration.

Here is what I have tried:

```
# Relative path points to the local folder
folder.path="../data/InauguralSpeeches/"

# get the list of file names
speeches=list.files(path = folder.path, pattern = "*.txt")

for(i in 1:length(speeches))
  {

    text_df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(speeches[i],read.csv))

}
```

Moreover, I have tried the following:

```
library(data.table)  
files <- list.files(path = folder.path,pattern = ".csv")
temp <- lapply(files, fread, sep=",")
data <- rbindlist( temp )
```

And it is giving me this error when inaugAbrahamLincoln-1.csv clearly exists in the folder:

```
files <- list.files(path = folder.path,pattern = ".csv")
> temp <- lapply(files, fread, sep=",")
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  File 'inaugAbrahamLincoln-1.csv' does not exist. Include one or more spaces to consider the input a system command.
> data <- rbindlist( temp )
Error in rbindlist(temp) : object 'temp' not found
>
```

But it only works on .csv files, not on .txt files.

Is there a simpler way to do text mining from multiple sources files? If so how?

Thanks

Comment: Show the code you tried and describe exactly how it isn't working. Have you used the `tm` package for text mining at all? You can load multiple files with the `DirSource()` function. Check out the [introduction to the tm package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf)

Comment: show the loop code you have tried so far.

Comment: @MrFlick  I was able to load the files into R through a corpus, but is there a way to load it into a data frame?

Comment: You actually got pretty far. You just forgot to include the relative path in your `speeches` character vector, that's why it can't find the file.

Comment: Thanks @Chrisss I think the problem is now solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often have this same problem.  The **textreadr** package that I maintain is designed to make reading .csv, .pdf, .doc, and .docx documents and directories of these documents easy.  It would reduce what you're doing to:

```
textreadr::read_dir("../data/InauguralSpeeches/")
```

Your example is not reproducible so I do it below (please make your example reproducible in the future).

```
library(textreadr)

## Minimal working example
dir.create('delete_me')
file.copy(dir(system.file("docs/Maas2011/pos", package = "textreadr"), full.names=TRUE), 'delete_me', recursive=TRUE)
write.csv(mtcars, 'delete_me/mtcars.csv')
write.csv(CO2, 'delete_me/CO2.csv')
cat('test\n\ntesting\n\ntester', file='delete_me/00_00.txt')

## the read in of a directory
read_dir('delete_me')
```

### output

The output below shows the tibble output with each document registered in the `document` column.  For every line in the document there is one row for that document.  Depending on what's in the csv files this may not be fine grained enough.

```
##    document                                  content
## 1       0_9 Bromwell High is a cartoon comedy. It ra
## 2     00_00                                     test
## 3     00_00                                         
## 4     00_00                                  testing
## 5     00_00                                         
## 6     00_00                                   tester
## 7       1_7 If you like adult comedy cartoons, like 
## 8      10_9 I'm a male, not given to women's movies,
## 9      11_9 Liked Stanley & Iris very much. Acting w
## 10     12_9 Liked Stanley & Iris very much. Acting w
## ..      ...                                      ... 
## 141   mtcars "Ferrari Dino",19.7,6,145,175,3.62,2.77,
## 142   mtcars "Maserati Bora",15,8,301,335,3.54,3.57,1
## 143   mtcars "Volvo 142E",21.4,4,121,109,4.11,2.78,18
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is code that will read all the *.csv files in a directory to a single data.frame:

```
dir <- '~/Desktop/testcsv/'
files <- list.files(dir,pattern = '*.csv', full.names = TRUE)
data <- lapply(files, read.csv)
df <- do.call(rbind, data)
```

Notice that I added the argument `full.names = TRUE`. This will give you the absolute paths, which is why youre getting an error for "inaugAbrahamLincoln-1.csv" even though it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it.

```
library(data.table)
setwd("C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/CSV Files/")

WD="C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/CSV Files/"
# read headers
data<-data.table(read.csv(text="CashFlow,Cusip,Period"))

csv.list<- list.files(WD)
k=1

for (i in csv.list){
  temp.data<-read.csv(i)
  data<-data.table(rbind(data,temp.data))

  if (k %% 100 == 0)
    print(k/length(csv.list))

  k<-k+1
}
```